# Turn off all sounds from websites

Tags: firefox, sound, chromium

Often, I am listening to music of my choosing.  Is there a way to preemptively turn off all sounds originating from websites?  I don't want to click the 'mute' button once the page loads.  And sometimes, it won't even have a mute. :-/

I use Chromium and FireFox.

~~EDIT~~

I use XFCE, so my menu options are different.   Is this a gnome-specific utility?

Or, what is the command for this utility?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After an application has been launched and begun playing audio, you can mute it through the Sound Preferences menu:

[image: sound menu capture]

On the sound preferences tab you can selectively mute applications:[image: Sound preferences menu]

Since Flash plug-in is not part of the browser, it must be muted separately:
[image: Sound preferences, Firefox and flash]

Comment: You might mention that if you want to mute the web browser, you have to do it while a web site is actually playing sound; otherwise the browser/plugin-container won't show up in the list of applications.

Comment: Please add that you can need to mute Flash and the Browser. If Flash is run in a a different process (like Firefox does), it will be shown as a different slider on the tab- It is that plugin-container in your screenshot.

Comment: @michael That sounds like exactly what I want.  Is that a gnome-specific tool?  I use XFCE, although gnome is installed, so if I know what the utility is, I can probably run it manually.  But the menu is different: I don't have a Sound Preferences menu

Comment: @David: This is the default Ubuntu Sound Indicator. I don't know if indicators run on XFCE. Anyway this is a Pulse Audio feature, it should be exposed on other volume controls.

Comment: +1 I found it: right click on the volume icon has "Sound Preferences" as an option.  Also +1 to @javier for comment to look for flash separately.

Comment: Hmm.  Under the Applications tab, Banshee is the only program listed.  How do I get other programs to show up there?

Comment: Make then sound ;). It only shows programs that are silenced or currently playing sound.

Comment: @Javier, Ah, so once I silence a program, it will stay on the list?  Excellent!

Answer (score 0):

For Firefox, the [Muter extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/muter/) works perfectly for me. It adds a mute/unmute button to the add-on bar. That functionality should really be part of all web browsers but it isn't, so this extension seems to be the solution.

(Works for me on Firefox 21 / Ubuntu 12.04LTS)